# How can I keep responsive image in container when resizing screen

Tags: html, css

I have an image inside a container, I have to use bottom in negative in order to keep the part of the image that I want, the problem is that when I resize the screen into a smaller one, the image just disappears, how can I fix this?

HTML:

```
</section>
<section id="img">
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row content">
      <div id="imgcont">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/162/6155406-mountain-images.jpeg" />
         <div id="header">
            <div class="title">
               <h1>Title in image centered</h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row content text-center">
      <h1>More content, same section </h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#imgcont {
       overflow: hidden;
       height: 400px;
       max-height: 400px;
       position: relative;
}



#imgcont .img-responsive {
          display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -500px;
    }


.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.title h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 3rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Full code:

https://codepen.io/elunap/pen/Ebwwjv

Or is there another way around this? this is really bothering me, when I finnaly think I made it work, something new happens.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the changes to #imgcont .img-responsive class. Used display:flex to make the image flexible according to the browser size.

```css
body {
 color: white;
}

.navbar {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 border-radius: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


.row.content {
 min-height: 450px
}


#about {
 background-color: red;
}

#img {
 background-color: gray;
 height 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

#howto {
 background-color: #003300;
}

#imgcont {
      
       overflow: hidden;
       height: 400px;
       max-height: 400px;
       position: relative;
}



#imgcont .img-responsive {
       display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
    }


.title {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
}

.title h1 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 3rem;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
<section id="about">
   <div class="container-fluid text-center">
      <div class="row content">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
<section id="img">
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row content">
      <div id="imgcont">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.qygjxz.com/data/out/162/6155406-mountain-images.jpeg" />
         <div id="header">
            <div class="title">
               <h1>Title in image centered</h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row content text-center">
      <h1>More content, same section </h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   </div>
</section>
<section id="howto">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row content">
         <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If I remove the " bottom: -500px;" it doesn't show the part of the image that I want, so I still have that problem

Answer (score 0):

You just need to comment below css from your code, for the responsive banner image.

```css
#imgcont .img-responsive {
       display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -500px;
    }
```